# ConfigParser (Python) empty values become empty string instead of "None" as documentation says

Tags: python, configparser

This paragraph does not change with the latest versions of Python, starting from 3.6 up to 3.10

> When allow_no_value is True (default: False), options without values
> are accepted; the value held for these is None and they are serialized
> without the trailing delimiter.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/configparser.html

Unfortunately, by not entering a value in a configuration file option, once in runtime, it becomes an empty string:

**Configuration file:**

```
[Conf Section]
sftp server = 1.2.3.4
sftp port =
```

**Python code:**

```
cf = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
sftp_server = cf.get('Conf Section', 'sftp server')
sftp_port = cf.get('Conf Section', 'sftp port')
```

**Runtime:**

```
>>> sftp_server 
1.2.3.4

>>> sftp_port 
''

>>> type(sftp_port) 
<class 'str'>
```

As you can see the sftp_port value is not a NoneType

The documentation behaviour is consistent if we try to search a non-existent option (in the "Conf Section"): 
**(We must use the fallback option)**

**Python code:**

```
cf = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
sftp_user = cf.get('Conf Section', 'sftp user', fallback=None)
```

**Runtime:**

```
>>> sftp_user
>>>

>>> type(sftp_user)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

But non-existent option ≠ to an empty option

Is something wrong or i'm the one who misinterpreted the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the following in the example in the docs:

```
[No Values]
key_without_value
empty string value here =
```

Comment: You're right, I had already used this method of declaration, I had forgotten about it

It's a pity that there is this distinction between option with equal sign and option without, especially because seeing an option without the sign makes me think that it's not a field to be filled in.

But it's definitely a cleaner option than leaving the sign and handling the empty string as a None, this to avoid using IF loops by writing ([if x == ' ':] , instead of [if x != None:])